# Azure Devops Pipeline job times out after 60 minutes when deploying APIM arm template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

I need to deploy an Azure API Management using Arm Template. It took more than 60 minutes to deploy. I am using microsoft hosted agent.

I assume it's because the status of the API-M is still in activating status even after 60 minutes.
[image]
The problem is, the pipeline would throw an error for anything that takes more than 60 minutes. Is there any solution/ workaround to deploy API-M using azure pipeline so it does not throw any errors in the pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

60 minutes sounds a bit long for APIM to activate. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance) mentions 30-40 minutes, but I guess there are situations where it can take as long as you experience.

To avoid errors for long running jobs in Azure devops you would need to increase the timeout of the running jobs. [The max timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts) (also the default) you can set depends on what type of agents you use (self hosted or microsoft hosted) as well as what type of project you have (public or private):

> To avoid taking up resources when your job is unresponsive or waiting too long, it's a good idea to set a limit on how long your job is allowed to run. Use the job timeout setting to specify the limit in minutes for running the job. Setting the value to zero means that the job can run:
>
> - Forever on self-hosted agents
> - For 360 minutes (6 hours) on Microsoft-hosted agents with a public project >and public repository
> - For 60 minutes on Microsoft-hosted agents with a private project or private repository (unless additional capacity is paid for)

It looks like you are using microsoft hosted agents from your screenshot, and since it times out after 60 seconds I guess you have a private repository. Your options then is either to

1. Use [self hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)
2. [Buy Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#microsoft-hosted-cicd), which will increase your [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations) to 360 minutes also for private repositories.

Comment: yes I am using a microsoft hosted agent. is there anyway that i can run job async-ly? basically once I trigger the arm template deployment for APIM stage, that's it, i just move on to the next job in the pipeline stage.

Comment: Yes, that would be an option, but you would not get any feedback on success and the rest of the pipeline cannot depend on the result of the deployment. Exactly hw you would go about it depends on how you trigger the arm deployment Is it a script (like powershell or bash) or are you using some built in task? Please share your code